# How can I navigate to a new screen with varied data from a lazy vertical grid in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

[Subject Section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSEI9.jpg)

As shown in the above image, I want to navigate to subject screen from this home screen.
But I want data of that subject to load into new screen when clicked on each subjects.

Right now, it leads me to same subject when I click on any item of lazy vertical grid.

[Subject Screen(Biology)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8XREn.jpg)
[Subject Screen(Physics)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EXXN.jpg)

**Home Screen[Subject Section]**

```
@Composable
fun SubjectSection(onClick: () -> Unit, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {


    Text(
        text = "Subjects",
        style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleMedium
    )

    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(8.dp))

    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        //contentPadding = PaddingValues(8.dp)
    ) {
        items(subjectList, key = { it.id }) { subject ->
            SubjectBox(subject = subject) {
                onClick()
            }
        }
    }
}


@Composable
fun SubjectBox(subject: Subject, onClick: () -> Unit) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .padding(end = 8.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
            .background(subject.color, RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
            .width(140.dp)
            .height(40.dp)
            .clickable { onClick() }
    ) {
        TextButton(
            onClick = onClick,
            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterStart)
        ) {
            Text(
                text = subject.name,
                style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                modifier = Modifier
                //.padding(start = 5.dp)
                //.align(Alignment.CenterStart)
            )
        }

        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = subject.image),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .size(60.dp)
                .padding(end = 5.dp)
                .align(Alignment.CenterEnd)
        )
    }
}
```

**Function Call**

```
SubjectSection(onClick = { navController.navigate(Screen.SubjectPhysics.route) })
```

**Subject Screen**

```
@Composable
fun SubjectScreen(
    subjects: Subjects,
    categories: List<ChapterCategory>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {

    Column {
        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .wrapContentSize(align = TopCenter)
                .background(color = Color(0xFFF9E9FE))
        )
        {
            Column {
                HeaderSection {
                }
                SubjectNameBox(subjects)
            }
        }
        Box(modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            ChapterColumn(categories = categories)
        }


    }


}

@Composable
fun HeaderSection(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    onBack: () -> Unit
) {
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(start = 0.dp, end = 20.dp, top = 20.dp, bottom = 20.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {

        IconButton(onClick = onBack) {
            Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = null)
        }
        Icon(
            imageVector = Icons.Default.Search,
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.align(CenterVertically)
        )
    }


}

@Composable
fun SubjectNameBox(subjects: Subjects, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Row(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(20.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
    ) {
        Text(
            text = subjects.name,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineLarge
        )
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = subjects.iconResId), contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier.size(80.dp)
        )
    }

}

@Composable
fun ChapterBox(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    chapterName: ChapterName
) {

    Box(
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(2.dp)
            .background(color = Color(0xFF8F6F5FA), RoundedCornerShape(8.dp))
    )
    {
        Row(
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(16.dp)
        ) {

            Image(painter = painterResource(id = chapterName.icon), contentDescription = null)
            Column {
                Text(text = chapterName.name, maxLines = 1, overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis)
                Spacer(Modifier.height(4.dp))
                Text(
                    text = chapterName.description,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                    maxLines = 1,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis
                )
            }
        }

    }

}


@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun ChapterColumn(
    categories: List<ChapterCategory>,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {


    LazyColumn() {

        categories.forEach { category ->
            stickyHeader {
                ChapterHeader(category.name)
            }
            items(category.chapters) { chapter ->
                ChapterBox(chapterName = chapter)
            }
        }
    }

}

@Composable
fun ChapterHeader(
    category: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    Text(
        text = category,
        fontSize = 16.sp,
        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
        modifier = modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primaryContainer)
            .padding(16.dp)
    )
}
```

**Subjects sealed class**

```
sealed class Subjects(val name: String, val iconResId: Int, val chapters: List<ChapterName>)


object Chemistry : Subjects(" Chemistry", R.drawable.chemistry, chapterNameChemistryOrganic)
object Biology : Subjects(" Biology", R.drawable.biology, chapterNameChemistryOrganic)
object Physics : Subjects(" Physics", R.drawable.physics3, chapterNameChemistryOrganic)


object Mat : Subjects("MAT", R.drawable.maths1, chapterNameMat)
object MockTest : Subjects("Mock Test", R.drawable.maths1, chapterNameMockTest)
```

**Chapter Category data class**

```
data class ChapterCategory(
    val name: String,
    val chapters: List<ChapterName>
)


val allChaptersChemistry = listOf(
    ChapterCategory("Physical Chemistry", chapterNameChemistryPhysical),
    ChapterCategory("Organic Chemistry", chapterNameChemistryOrganic),
    ChapterCategory("Inorganic Chemistry", chapterNameChemistryInorganic),
)

val allChaptersBiology = listOf(
    ChapterCategory(name = "Zoology", chapters = chapterNameBiologyZoology),
    ChapterCategory(name = "Botany", chapters = chapterNameBiologyBotany)
)

val allChaptersPhysics = listOf(
    ChapterCategory(name = "Mechanics", chapters = chapterNamePhysicsMechanics),
    ChapterCategory(name = "Thermodynamics", chapters = chapterNamePhysicsThermodynamics),
    ChapterCategory(name = "Sound", chapters = chapterNamePhysicsSound),
    ChapterCategory(name = "Optics", chapters = chapterNamePhysicsOptics),
    ChapterCategory(name = "Electrostatics", chapters = chapterNamePhysicsElectrostatics),
    ChapterCategory(
        name = "Electricity And Magnetism",
        chapters = chapterNamePhysicsElectricityAndMagnetism
    ),
    ChapterCategory(name = "Modern Physics", chapters = chapterNamePhysicsModernPhysics),
)
```

**Navigation**

```
@Composable
fun NavigationScreen() {

    val navController = rememberNavController()

    NavHost(
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = Screen.Navigation.route
    ) {
        composable(route = Screen.Home.route) {
            HomeScreen(navController)
        }

        composable(route = Screen.Navigation.route) {
            BottomNavigationScreen(navController)
        }


        composable(route = Screen.SubjectPhysics.route) {
            SubjectScreen(subjects = Physics, categories = allChaptersPhysics)
        }
        composable(route = Screen.SubjectChemistry.route) {
            SubjectScreen(subjects = Chemistry, categories = allChaptersChemistry)
        }
        composable(route = Screen.SubjectBiology.route) {
            SubjectScreen(subjects = Biology, categories = allChaptersBiology)
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are navigating to same subject screen because of you are calling the same logic on all the item click as below.

**Problem**
You are passing nothing here on ItemClick. so it leads to same page for all items.

```
items(subjectList, key = { it.id }) { subject ->
            SubjectBox(subject = subject) {
                onClick()
            }
        }
```

**Function Call**

```
SubjectSection(onClick = { navController.navigate(Screen.SubjectPhysics.route) })
```

**Solution**
So what you can do is send some variable or value which will be used to distinguish the subjects.

So you can define a unique key for subject name and on which you can filter the page route.

```
items(subjectList, key = { it.id }) { subject ->
                SubjectBox(subject = subject) {
                    onClick(subject.name)
                }
            }
```

and on function call you add when or if and set the route as per that.

```
SubjectSection(onClick = {route ->
        if(route == "Chemistry") {
            navController.navigate(Screen.SubjectChemistry.route)
        }else if(route == "Biology"){
            navController.navigate(Screen.SubjectBiology.route)
        }else{
            navController.navigate(Screen.SubjectPhysics.route)
        }
    })
```

Comment: How can I  use Nav arguments to load items in lazy vertical grid? Won't that be a better approach?

Comment: Yes that is the way but as per your current code this fits best

Comment: What modifications are needed to implement it using Nav arguments? I'm stuck with Nav arguments and can't find a solution using it though your solution using conditionals works just fine.